# Some .wav files wont play

Tags: html, google-chrome

I would like to ask what could be the possible reasons why some .wav files won't play in Google Chrome Browser.

Is there any way that I could play .wav files just using the Google Chrome Browser?

Answer (score 1):

try with below HTML5 code this my help you. and some files will not support due to file will have artist and its invalid formate which will be missing so it wont support.

```html
<audio controls>
<source src="http://www.externalharddrive.com/waves/animal/dolphin.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Chromium bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83323

The gist of it is that .wav can mean a bunch of things and have various encodings. The comments recommend using a plugin to handle this or downloading the file.